# How to write to the client twice?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to send to the client the bits he has to read, then he has to read them. But for some reason he doesn't read the message, he only reads the bites,`msgLength`.I get the message form the server`[server]The message was sent succefully.`And the client is able to read only the `msgLength`, the `msg` is empty. 
client:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

extern int errno;

int port;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int sd;                   
  struct sockaddr_in server; 
  char msg[200];            
  int fd;
  char msgLength[200];

  
  if (argc != 3)
  {
    printf("Sintax: %s <adress_server> <port>\n", argv[0]);
    return -1;
  }

  
  port = atoi(argv[2]);

 
  if ((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
  {
    perror("Error on socket().\n");
    return errno;
  }


 
  server.sin_family = AF_INET;

  server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);

  server.sin_port = htons(port);


  if (connect(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
  {
    perror("[client]Erorr on connect().\n");
    return errno;
  }
     
  if (recv(sd, msgLength, 2,0) < 0)
  {
    perror("[client]Erorr on recv() from the server.\n");
    return errno;
  }
  bzero(msg,100);
  if (recv(sd, msg, 22,0)<0){
    perror("[client]Erorr on the second recv() from the server.\n");
    return errno;
  }
printf("msgLength: %s\n",msgLength);
 
  printf("[client]The message recived is: %s\n", msg);

  close(sd);
}
```

server:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define PORT 2024


extern int errno;

int main()
{
  struct sockaddr_in server; r
  struct sockaddr_in from;
  char msg[100];           
  char msgrasp[100] = " "; 
  int sd;                  
  pid_t pid;

  
  if ((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
  {
    perror("[server]Erorr on the socket().\n");
    return errno;
  }

  
  bzero(&server, sizeof(server));
  bzero(&from, sizeof(from));


  server.sin_family = AF_INET;

  server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

  server.sin_port = htons(PORT);

  int optval = 1;
  setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(optval));
  setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &optval, sizeof(optval));

    */
      if (bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
  {
    perror("[server]Erorr on the bind().\n");
    return errno;
  }

  if (listen(sd, 5) == -1)
  {
    perror("[server]Erorr on listen().\n");
    return errno;
  }

 
  while (1)
  {
    int client;
    int length = sizeof(from);

    printf("[server]We wait on the port %d...\n", PORT);
    fflush(stdout);

    
    client = accept(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&from, &length);

   
    if (client < 0)
    {
      perror("[server]Erorr on accept().\n");
      continue;
    }

    switch (pid = fork())
    {
    case -1:
      perror("fork");
      exit(1);
      break;
    case 0:
      close(sd);
      
      bzero(msg, 100);
      printf("[server]Sending the text...\n");
      fflush(stdout);

      int fd1 = open("ToSend.txt", O_RDONLY);
      char msgLength[100];
      read(fd1, msgrasp, 100);
      sprintf(msgLength,"%ld",strlen(msgrasp)+1);
      printf("msgLength: %d\n",atoi(msgLength));

      
      if ((send(client,msgLength,sizeof(msgLength),0) && send(client, msgrasp, atoi(msgLength),0)) <= 0)
      {
        perror("[server]Erorr on send() to the client.\n");
        continue; 
      }
      else
        printf("[server]The message was sent succefully.\n");

     
      exit(2);

    default:
      wait(NULL);
      close(client);
      break;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Calls to `send()` and `recv()` should really have their return values examined more closely, especially `recv()` to get the actual number of bytes received.

Comment: Make a decision: is a usage statement an error message or is it informational?  If it is an error message, it should be written to stderr and the program should return non-zero.  If it is informational, it should be written to stdout and the program should exit zero.  Writing the message to stdout and returning -1 is schizophrenic.  IMO, a usage statement should not be written in place of a proper error message, and the recent propagation of tools that spew usage statements instead of a terse error message is a travesty.

Comment: @SteveFriedl I checked. If the server writes n bites, the recv from client, returns n, but `msg` is empty

Comment: You should not be using `strlen()` to count the bytes received; instead look at the return value from `recv()`. And why is the code doing this? `printf("msgLength: %d\n",atoi(msgLength));` after formatting the count into a string?

Comment: I did `int recvB=recv(sd, msg, atoi(msgLength),0)` and i got the bytes. And i do this `printf("msgLength: %d\n",atoi(msgLength));` just to print to see if the server sends the right info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was that the server was sending `sizeof(msgLength)` witch is 100, and the client was reading just 2. If i replace `sizeof(msgLength)` with `strlen(msgLength)+1` it works just fine. Thank you all for your time.